# Dynamically creating "LPCWSTR" variable from std::string variable

Tags: string, winapi, type-conversion, wchar

Currently I have the code (`typedef _Null_terminated_ CONST WCHAR *LPCWSTR;`):

```
LPCWSTR wchar_string(L"ABC");
```

But need to enable something like this:

```
std::string s("ABC");
...
LPCWSTR wchar_string(/* create somehow from variable s */);
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::string` is an 8-bit character string.  `wchar_string` is an array of Wide (UTF-16) code points.  That requires by definition that a transcoding operation take place, and it's not just a simple assignment.

First, how is the 8-bit string encoded?  Is it UTF-8, Windows ANSI "current code page", Latin-1 only, or what?

Second, call a function like Windows' [`MultiByteToWideChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to do the heavy lifting, and be sure to manage memory for the result buffer that wchar_string is pointing to.